# split list to multiple list on property basis

Tags: c#, linq

i have a class as below

```
 public class Flight
  {
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public int Set{get;set;}

    public Flight(int companyId, int number, int set)
    {
        this.CompanyId = companyId;
        this.Number = number;
        this.Set=set;
    }
}
```

i have a list of this type

```
var flights = new List<Flight>
            {
                new Flight(10, 10000,1), 
                new Flight(20, 20000,2), 
                new Flight(30, 30000,3),
                new Flight(40, 40000,4),
                new Flight(50, 50000,5),
            };
```

i want to split this list to 3 lists or object[] on properties each of type int (or the type to which it belongs), the expected result is

```
        object[] lista = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 40 };
        object[] listb = { 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000 };
        object[] listc = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

can this be achieved through linq?

edit:sorry for not mentioning this, the list above may have dynamic properties, so i just want to check if it can be dynamically done?

Comment: if you are down voting please mention the reason as well, simply down voting does not explain!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just select the properties and convert it to an array:

```
var lista = flights.Select(f => f.CompanyId).ToArray();
var listb = flights.Select(f => f.Number).ToArray();
var listc = flights.Select(f => f.Set).ToArray();
```

Comment: @stefankmitph-actually the list properties may be dynamic.i want to do it dynamically.

Comment: so how come you have a constructor with parameters when you're dealing with dynamic properties?

Comment: for SO Q&A purpose i built it,to make the question more easy to understand, sorry if i have led to any confusions,

Answer (score 2):

Here you go

```
List<List<Flight>> result = flights
  .GroupBy(Flight => Flight.PropertyA)
  .Select(g => g.ToList())
  .ToList();
```

Above way will scale if you add more properties in class without any modification. If your class is fixed then do it is as follows,

```
var listCompanyId = flights.Select(f => f.CompanyId).ToArray();
var listNumber = flights.Select(f => f.Number).ToArray();
var listSet = flights.Select(f => f.Set).ToArray();
```